# recursive method asking for an integer from 1 to 10

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I'm trying to write a method that should recursively ask the user to enter a value from 1 to 10 inclusive.

This is what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int value = readGoodInput();
     System.out.println("The user entered: " + value);

}

public static int readGoodInput(){

    int value;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
    value = input.nextInt();

    if (value <= 10 && value >= 1){

        return value;       
    }
    else{

        readGoodInput();

    }
    return value;

}
```

When I run the program:

Enter a value: 
**11**

Enter a value: 
**22**

Enter a value: 
**3**

The user entered: 11

My question is: why does the value that get printed last is not 3, which is between 1 and 10,  but 11?

Thank you in advance,

Didi

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of recursion.  Is this a class where the instructor is requiring you to do it this way?

Comment: Oh yes... unfortunately.

Comment: Why, why, why, why, why, why, why, _why_ ... can't instructors figure out how to teach about recursion without forcing students to write terrible code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value:

```
else {
    return readGoodInput();
}
```

Otherwise the code gets executed but the *"good input"* is never returned, only the first one.

Comment: This fixes OP's issue but does not explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to follow your recursion carefully. See where the recursion happens and what values are returned. See comments below to serve as a guide.

Your first recursion value is never changed in the following recursion calls. Therefore the value used the first time will be the value shown in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int value = readGoodInput();
     System.out.println("The user entered: " + value);

}

public static int readGoodInput(){

    int value;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
    value = input.nextInt();

    if (value <= 10 && value >= 1){
        // readGoodInput()3 returns value of 3 to readGoodInput()2
        return value;       
    }
    else{
        // readGoodInput()1 returns value of 11 to main's readGoodInput()
        // readGoodInput()2 returns value of 22 to readGoodInput()1

        readGoodInput();  // This is where your recursion happens.


    }

    return value; // This will return the first readGoodInput() value.

}
```

If you want it to return 3 after the recursion completes... set your value = to the recursive method.

```
        else{
        value = readGoodInput();  // This is where your recursion happens.


    }
```

Comment: Why does the final return value; return the first readGoodInput() value?

Comment: Treat each recursion as its own case.

Comment: Also notice how its not `value = readGoodInput()` I've actually been stumped by this type of question before.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to explain your next question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do a recursion you can achieve this by using while loop since it's a pretty simple operation.

But if you have more  logic to be put into that function then maybe recursion is needed.

```
public static int readGoodInput(){

    int value = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(value < 1 || value > 10){
         System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
         value = input.nextInt();
    }

    return value;
}
```